# Find Last Column, Back Calculate & Select All

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to conduct the following:
1. Find the last column with data from cell A4 until end
2. Back calculate last column by - 6 columns
3. Select the entire range of columns from -6 to last column (last code listed below does not work)

```
lastcol = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
fircol = lastcol - 6
Columns(fircol & ":" & lastcol).Select
```

Comment: In the last line, change `Columns` to `Range`... but note that [you probably shouldn't `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to begin with.

Comment: @BigBen , i tried that & the macro ended up selecting rows 200++ instead which i am unsure why

Comment: Oh sorry... yeah I'm thinking of `Rows`, not `Columns`... Use `Columns(fircol).Resize(,6)`.

Comment: that worked.Awesome ! thanks a lot